# How can I run the psql server properly if my path is not recognized?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I'm trying to run a PSQL server through the windows comand line, the instruction is:

```
postgres -d /usr/local/pgsql/data
```

The problem is that my bin file is in the program files directory, so when I use this path :

```
postgres -D C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin
```

I get this error :

> postgres : argument invalide : « Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin »

Someone knows how I can run the psql server?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put double quotes around the path